# I'm learning python programming and have a problem with a code that I wrote

Tags: python

I was given this exercise: create a function that gets the person dictionary, and a parentFIrstName as a string. The function will search for the parent in the dictionary and will return true or false  - if exists or not.
I wrote a code but it gives me only the  person dictionary and a parentFIrstName as a string, but doesn't give me True or False. what's the problem?

```
person = {'Firstname': "christina", 'Lastname': "hidden from stackoverflow", 'Email': "hidden from stackoverflow" ,'Phone':"hidden from stackoverflow"}
parent = {'Firstname': "galina", 'Lastname': "hidden from stackoverflow", 'Email': "hidden from stackoverflow" ,'Phone':"hidden from stackoverflow"}
def personAndParentFirstName():
   print(person, parent['Firstname'])
   for i in person:
       if (i == parent['Firstname']):
           return True
   return False
personAndParentFirstName()
```

```
[Running] python -u "c:\Users\darks\Documents\HELLO\test\test2.py"
{'Firstname': 'christina', 'Lastname': 'hidden from stackoverflow', 'Email': 'hidden from stackoverflow', 'Phone': 'hidden from stackoverflow'} galina

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.139 seconds
```

Comment: [Formatting posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: It does give you True or False. It’s just that you don’t print it out.

Comment: Titles are supposed to give some indication of the content of the question.

Comment: I don't see True or False when i'm running the code

Comment: That’s because you don’t print it out.

Comment: what do you mean by saying "because you don't print it out"? I don't understand what you mean

Comment: You could have written: print(personAndParentFirstName())

Comment: I understood and now it's working, thanks! didn't know that I can print out fuctions. i'm a beginner

Comment: The print() prints out the value that is returned from the function. That’s what your return statements are doing.

Answer (score 1):

solution1:

```
def personAndParentFirstName():
   print(person, parent['Firstname'])
   if person['Firstname'] ==  parent['Firstname']:
       return True
   else:
       return False
print (personAndParentFirstName())
```

solution2:

```
def personAndParentFirstName():
   print(person, parent['Firstname'])
   for i in person.values():
       if (i == parent['Firstname']):
           return True
       else:
           return False
print (personAndParentFirstName())
```

NOTE: you cant iterate over dictionary **values** like this:

```
for i in person:
```

> There are multiple ways to iterate over a dictionary in Python.
>
> Iterate through all keys
>
> Iterate through all values
>
> Iterate through all key, value pairs

NOTE: function is returning true or false but you are not using it. print result of function like

```
print (personAndParentFirstName())
```

Comment: what does person.values gives? and is "# iterate over values"  has to be written in the code? didn't learn about these things. thanks

Comment: I just edited my code @scorpio11

Comment: Comments in Python start with the hash character, #. easy way to increase the readability of your code is by using comments!

Comment: So is " for i in "used only when iterating over list? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As quamrana says, you need to print it out:

```
person = {'Firstname': "christina", 'Lastname': "hidden from stackoverflow", 'Email': "hidden from stackoverflow" ,'Phone':"hidden from stackoverflow"}
parent = {'Firstname': "galina", 'Lastname': "hidden from stackoverflow", 'Email': "hidden from stackoverflow" ,'Phone':"hidden from stackoverflow"}
def personAndParentFirstName():
   print(person, parent['Firstname'])
   for i in person.values():
       if (i == parent['Firstname']):
           return True
   return False
print("Is parent: "+str(personAndParentFirstName()))
```